# .htaccess: something more than "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ..."

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have several domains for my page: https://www.mypage.es, https://www.mypage.it.... Now I'm trying to redirect just my french domain https://www.mypage.fr to https://www.mypage.com. So I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule https://www.mypage.fr$ https://www.mypage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but doesn't redirect...

NOTE: This redirects ok:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mypage\.fr
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.mypage.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mypage\.fr
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mypage.com$1 [R=301,L]
```